# How create function that takes as an argument the name of an operating system

Tags: java

How i create a function in JAVA that takes as an argument the name of an operating system folder and returns the number of files in the folder as well as all its subfolders ?

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files` has some interesting methods like `find`, `walk` and `walkFileTree`

Answer (score 2):

> returns the number of files in the folder as well as all its subfolders ?

Its easy to do using the java [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API. The methods you are interested in start with the word `list`

**Number of files in a dir**

```
var numFilesInDir = new File(<directory path>).listFiles().length
```

**Getting subdirectory list**

```
File myDir = new File(<directory path>);
String[] myDirSubdirectoryNames = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
    return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
```

Does this solve your problem ? Leave me a comment to tell.

Comment: Οhhh Thank you very much, yes it solves my problem and sorry if I did not formulate the question correctly.

Comment: If this answer has helped you solve your problem please feel free to mark it as accepted so its easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to count all files in the directory and all subdirectories you likely need a file tree walker:

```
long count = Files.walk(startPath)
    .filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p))
    .count();
```

There are lots of options for what type of files to include in the walk and maximum depth etc. You can also write your own `FileVisitor` to do more sophisticated things for each file. See Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html for all the details.

One particular thing to be aware of is that the walk leaves directories open until they are closed. The easiest way to ensure this is done is to use a try-with-resources block to ensure the directories are closed even if an exception is thrown.

For example:

```
try(var walk = Files.walk(Path.of("/mypath"))) {
    long count = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p)).count();
    ...
} catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for the QA!

Comment: You should close the stream. See [Files.wark()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))

Comment: That's pretty clear in the doc but I can add a note.